# How to write 2 matrices with different types of data to a single file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, file-io

I have 2 matrices, with one having floating point numbers and the other, integer numbers. Both the matrices have the same number of rows but different number of columns.

I want to write both the matrices together to a file with each single line consisting of a single row from each matrix printed side-by-side.

How should I do this?

My try (unsuccessful) :

```
    fid = fopen(nameF, 'w'); % Open for writing
    fprintf('%d\n',fid);
    for i=1:size(FloatMat,1)
        fprintf(fid, '%f %d ', FloatMat(i,:),IntMat(i,:));
        fprintf(fid, '\n');
    end
    fclose(fid);
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with it? One thing I would suggest though is to get rid of that trailing space per row: `fprintf(fid, '%f %d ', FloatMat(i,:),IntMat(i,1:end-1)); fprintf(fid, '%d\n', IntMat(i,end));`

Comment: Well, as @BlackAdder says in his answer below, alternate float and integer values were getting printed as opposed to all the columns of `FloatMat` (as `float` type) and then all the columns of `IntMat` (as `int` type). `repmat` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `%f` and `%d` of your `fprintf` only refers to the **first** and **second** columns. If there are more columns Matlab will repeat the pattern.

So you are saving the first column of `FloatMat` as `float`, the second column of `FloatMat` as `Integer`, etc...

You must specify the type of each column, but don't worry, you don't have to do it manually, use `repmat` instead

```
fprintf(fid, [repmat('%f ',1,size(FloatMat,2)) ' ' ...
              repmat('%d ',1,size(IntMat,2)) '\n'], ...
              FloatMat(i,:), IntMat(i,:));
```

PD: Note that I have separated the columns with space, as you did. Feel free to use `\t` or comma to separate them if needed.

PD: Also you can include the `\n` in the same line, so you can save one line of code.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem. I did not know about repmat. However I had to change the dimension of the matrix to get  the correct formatting . This helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This one actually writes both in float format with 8 digits precision, you will not get `%d` effect here but is only two lines:

```
BothMat = [FloatMat IntMat]
save(nameF, 'BothMat', '-ascii')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to complicate things using `repmat` int his case, just `fprintf` the float matrix first followed by the int matirx:

```
nRows = 5;
Mint = magic(nRows);
Mfloat = rand(nRows, 3);
fid = fopen('test.txt','w');
for row = 1:nRows
    fprintf(fid,'%f\t', Mfloat(row,:));
    fprintf(fid,'%d\t',Mint(row,1:end-1)); % only go to end to prevent trailing delimiter after final value of the row
    fprintf(fid,'%d\n',Mint(row,end));
end
fclose(fid);
```

example output

```
0.392227    0.276923    0.317099    17  24  1   8   15
0.655478    0.046171    0.950222    23  5   7   14  16
0.171187    0.097132    0.034446    4   6   13  20  22
0.706046    0.823458    0.438744    10  12  19  21  3
0.031833    0.694829    0.381558    11  18  25  2   9
```

Comment: What is the reason for printing the end separately and not at one go? I noticed your comment about preventing trailing delimiters but I did not understand the significance.

Comment: @creativesol so in my case I was using tabs to delimit but you used spaces so you will have line like this `1 2 3 ` with that trailing space whereas by printing the last line separately you'll get `1 2 3` which I think is cleaner. Even the markdown in this comment is confused by the trailing space ;)